# How can I change order of values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['banana','apple','pie','mango','cola'],
                    'col2':['apple','banana','mango','cola','mango'],
                     })
df3['col3']=df3['col1']+df3['col2']
```

result

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   banana  apple   bananaapple
1   apple   banana  applebanana
2   pie     mango   piemango
3   mango   cola    mangocola
4   cola    mango   colamango
```

change

```
col1    col2    col3
0   banana  apple   bananaapple
1   apple   banana  bananaapple
2   pie     mango   piemango
3   mango   cola    mangocola
4   cola    mango   mangocola
```

what I want to do is filter if string(ab=ba) change to ab

Comment: please be clear. what do you mean with ab ba? do you mean if col1 = col2, change col3?

Comment: I mean order of column if they are same col1 col2 = col2 col1 I want to change col1 col2

Comment: Does the order of a and b matter? If not, you can get col1 and col2 as a list of 2 elements, sort it and then create a string.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, based on your example and your explanation, your expectation translates to simply sorting each row and joining them.

Assuming that you have access to `col1` and `col2`, you can remove the addition of the 2 columns elementwise, and try this -

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['banana','apple','pie','mango','cola'],
                    'col2':['apple','banana','mango','cola','mango']})

#df3['col3']=df3['col1']+df3['col2'] ### REMOVE THIS

df3['col4'] = df3.apply(sorted, reverse=True, axis=1).str.join('')
print(df3)
```

```
     col1    col2         col4
0  banana   apple  bananaapple
1   apple  banana  bananaapple
2     pie   mango     piemango
3   mango    cola    mangocola
4    cola   mango    mangocola
```

**EDIT:** Updated with vectorized `str` function for joining the list of strings, which is significantly faster than `.apply()`